# git: default to no-ff, but allow fast-forwarding when pulling from remotes

Tags: git

I know you can use `git config merge.ff false` to make it so any time I merge a branch, it defaults to using the `--no-ff` option. I like this, but one annoying thing is that since I enabled it, it seems that when I pull from the remote, it merges the remote branch into the local.

I'd like to make is so that when I do a local `git merge other_branch`, I get a merge commit, but when I do `git pull origin this_branch`, it will fast-forward if possible.

Can this be done?

Comment: My personal preference is not to use `git pull` at all, and control this on the command line (I use an alias, `git mff`, to do the merge-fast-forward when I mean to do that, and do a real merge when I mean that...). But phd's answer is good.

Answer (score 4):

[`git config pull.ff true`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pullff)

This setting overrides `merge.ff` when pulling.